# Weird seg fault when erasing from a map

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
//update it in the map
      std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
      for(it = spreadsheets.at(i).cells.begin(); it != spreadsheets.at(i).cells.end(); ++it)
      {
        if(it->first == change.first)
        {
          if(change.second == "")
          {
            spreadsheets.at(i).cells.erase(change.first);
          }
          else
          {
          it->second = change.second;
          }
        }
      }
```

The code above **runs perfectly on my mac** however when I **run in on a linux computer** it throws a seg fault on `spreadsheets.at(i).cells.erase(change.first);`

Any idea whats causing this error? Ive tried changing `erase(change.first)` to `erase(it)` and I am still getting the seg fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of `std::map::erase`:

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

Still your loop goes on and you increment your (now invalid) iterator.

Fix: increment your iterator another way, eg.:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
for (it = spreadsheets.at(i).cells.begin(); it != spreadsheets.at(i).cells.end();/*NOTE: no increment here*/)
{
  if (it->first == change.first)
  {
    if (change.second == "")
    {
      it = spreadsheets.at(i).cells.erase(it); // C++11 only
      // in both C++03 and C++11:  spreadsheets.at(i).cells.erase(it++);
    }
    else
    {
      it->second = change.second;
      ++it;
    }
  }
  else
    ++it;
}
```

Or to avoid confusion because of the numerous execution paths (the very same confusion that made me forget the last `else` on my first try): just copy the iterator, increment the original one, and then use the copy. This may look overkill in your case but for more complex loops this is sometimes the only way to stay sane. ;)

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
for (it = spreadsheets.at(i).cells.begin(); it != spreadsheets.at(i).cells.end();/*NOTE: no increment here*/)
{
  std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator this_it = it++;
  if (this_it->first == change.first)
  {
    if (change.second == "")
    {
      spreadsheets.at(i).cells.erase(this_it);
    }
    else
    {
      this_it->second = change.second;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Deekor: incrementing an invalidated iterator is Undefined Behaviour, which means basically "anything could happen" (it could even have the *appearance* of working, which is what happens on your Mac).

Comment: @Deekor: I updated my code, there was a path where I forgot to increment the iterator (the last `else`). Be sure to double-check it or you will have a bug.

Comment: @syam, in C++03 it's enough to simply put `spreadsheets.at(i).cells.erase(it++);` as post increment returns a copy of the iterator.

Comment: @W.B. Right, I'll fix that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Because I only needed to update one item I was able to just 'break' after the 'erase'

Answer (score 6):

Because when you erase from the container, your iterator is no longer valid, yet your loop continues.

You could change your loop to:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it = spreadsheets.at(i).cells.begin();
while (it != spreadsheets.at(i).cells.end())
{
  if(it->first == change.first)
  {
    if(change.second == "")
    {
      spreadsheets.at(i).cells.erase(it++);  //Post increment returns a copy pointing at the current element, while it already points to the next element and thus stays valid after erase
    }
    else
    {
      it->second = change.second;
      ++it;
    }
  }
  else
    ++it;
}
```

Now that I think of it, why do you erase with first element of the pair the iterator is pointing to, ie:

```
spreadsheets.at(i).cells.erase(change.first);
```

instead of

```
spreadsheets.at(i).cells.erase(it);
```

It's less efficient, as another lookup has to be made.

Answer (score 2):

After element being erased from map pointing to this element will become invalidated. Thus `spreadsheets.at(i).cells.erase(change.first);` renders `it` invalid. See [Iterator Invalidation Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Answer (score 1):

References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated.

```
//update it in the map
std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
for(it = spreadsheets.at(i).cells.begin(); it != spreadsheets.at(i).cells.end(); ++it)
{
    if(it->first == change.first)
    {
        if(change.second == "")
        {
            spreadsheets.at(i).cells.erase(it--);
        }
        else
        {
            it->second = change.second;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you do `spreadsheets.at(i).cells.erase(change.first);` the iterator in the std::map (at the current change.first key) is invalidated. So, when you do `it++`, it is undefined behaviour.

cf [Rules for Iterator Invalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114503/rules-for-iterator-invalidation) for rules about invalidation of iterators in standard containers

Answer (score 0):

Increment the iterator before you erase it. Why didn't it happen on the Mac? Who knows.. different OS, different behaviour.

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to)